# Symfony translating routes using BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle duplicate routes

Tags: php, symfony, routes, translation

I'm creating a multi language website and I'm using `BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle` for route translations. Route in my config looks like that:

```
about:
    locales:  { en: "/{_locale}/about-us", lt: "/{_locale}/apie-mus" }
    defaults: { _controller: BaseBundle:Base:about }
```

However in this case I get duplicate route as if I enter /en/about-us or /lt/about-us it works in both ways. but in the second way it should be 404 error because the route for lt locale should be /lt/apie-mus which also works fine.

Is there any way of fixing that? Or maybe any better ways of translating routes?

Answer (score 8):

> However in this case I get duplicate route

There is one route per language:

```
$ app/console router:debug
about.en                 ANY    ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/about-us
about.lt                 ANY    ANY    ANY  /{_locale}/apie-mus
```

When you are on the URL `/lt/about-us` the UrlMatcher will match the *en* version:

```
$ app/console router:match /lt/about-us
Route "about.en" matches

[router] Route "about.en"
Name         about.en
Path         /{_locale}/about-us
Path Regex   #^/(?P<_locale>[^/]++)/about\-us$#s
Host         ANY
Host Regex
Scheme       ANY
Method       ANY
Class        Symfony\Component\Routing\Route
Defaults     _controller: AppBundle:Default:index
             _locale: en
Requirements NO CUSTOM
Options      compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler
```

In this case, the local will be **en** and not **lt**.

But I don't think that you should worry about it because the only way that a visitor will visite `/lt/about-us` is by editing the URL himself.

Comment: that makes me worry if google can somehow index `/lt/about-us` and `/en/about-us` as it would be duplicate content for different URLS

Comment: If you generate urls like explained in the bundle: `{{ path('about', { 'locale': 'en' }) }}`
There is no reason for google to index urls that are not in your html. If it's not enough, you can generate a `robots.txt` or a `sitemap`.

Answer (score 4):

After battle with BeSimple I switched my project to JMSI18nRoutingBundle in 10 minutes. It works well and resolves problem with routes. Firstly: it containes multiple modes of prefixation (with locale) and secondly it allows to translate every route.